# X and Y random variables. How can I interpret $\sqrt{E(Y-X)^{2}}$ as the distance between X and Y?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

X and Y random variables. How can I interpret $\sqrt{E(Y-X)^{2}}$ as the distance between X and Y by showing (prooving) that i) and ii) below works:

1. if $\sqrt{E(Y-X)^{2}}$ = 0 then $P(Y=X)=1$
2. The triangle inequality works: $\sqrt{E(Y-X)^{2}}  \leq  \sqrt{E(Y^{2})} +\sqrt{E(X^{2})}$

So, I have to use i) and ii) to show that $\sqrt{E(Y-X)^{2}}$ can be interpretated as the distance between X and Y.

I am completely lost here.

Any help?

Comment: You just need to show the facts listed above. I guess you haven't learned about distance, so this might help: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A [distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metric_(mathematics)#Definition) function satisfies

1. $d(x,y)=0$ implies $x=y$
2. $d(x,y) \leq d(x,c)+d(c,y)$.

Here $d(x,y)=\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2}$ and $c=0$. In words, if the distance function is zero, the points are the same (distance from a point to itself is zero, right?). The triangle inequality just means that the distance from $x$ to $y$ is less than the sum of the distances from $x$ to $c$ and the distance from $c$ to $y$ where $c$ is some intermediate point. They ask you to prove $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(\cdot)}$ satisfies these two properties, so that it can be interpreted as a distance function.

They seemed to have omitted symmetry though...

Comment: So simple. Many many thanks!

Comment: One comment: I could have problem sugesting that $c=0$? There will be a number c more general?

Comment: Indeed. They only ask you to prove property 2) for the specific case $c=0$. In general, for this specific distance function (there are many!) you would show instead $\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X-Y)^2}\leq \sqrt{\mathbb{E}(X-Z)^2}+\sqrt{\mathbb{E}(Z-Y)^2}$.

Comment: Note, what I write here above and in my comment—is not a proof—you still need to *show* the two properties hold to finish the exercise. I was just trying to elucidate it what it *meant* to for a function $d(x,y)$ to be a distance function, since that is what seemed unfamiliar to you.

Comment: Yes, yes @LoveTooNap29 I understand. My question was not clear, but I understand your point.